# SharePoint formatting date column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am having an issue when trying to format my date column on a list.
I want the background color to turn red if the date is less than or equal to Today – 10 days, else its green.

I cant see how to figure it out.

Here is the JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column- 
    formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "if(@currentField >= @now + 864000000,'#f7cac9','#f7cac9')"
    }
}
```

I have tried to use `Date(@now,toDateString()`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this JSON

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(Number(@currentField)!=0, if(@currentField <= addDays(@now, -10),'red','green'),'')",
    "color": "white",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "padding-left": "15px"
  }
}
```

Here I have used `Number(@currentField)!=0` to check if SharePoint date column is blank or not. You can find other ways to check if SharePoint date & time column is empty or not at: [SharePoint JSON formatting: Check if date & time column is blank/empty](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/06/20/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-and-time-column-is-blank-empty/)

Also, if you want to refer the date column value in JSON using column name, you will have to use the *internal name* of column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)